# A lots of Apache processes are using my CPU uses always more than 70%

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, httpd

I am running a plesk panel in 1and1. I have 120 sites running and all are using pligg cms, each site has 600 visitors per day. Please see the details of my server below:

HDD-1000GB
RAM-16GB
Processor-6 Core

I always see a lot of apache processes running in my # top view, so the server seems overloaded. If I can reduce the amount apache processes I think the server will be ok. But I don't know why too many apache processes are running.

Please see the link below for the screenshot of my # top view:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26967109/%23Top-2.jpg

Sometimes I saw too many connection error in my plesk control panel, so I added the below line in my [mysqld] section:

set-variable=max_connections=416

But I didn't find a solution yet. I have also added maxclients and serverlimit 416 in the config /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

But no solution yet. I am researching around more than 7 days but don't get any solution. Please help me to solve the problem.

In peak hours my sites are taking too much time to load, but off-peak hour it is ok.

Please help me to find out the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of load, as EightBitTony suggested you should optimize your queries. If that is not possible, separate your webserver and database server. Get an additional server that does nothing else than reply to database requests.

Also check this is in your mysql configuration:

- `thread_concurrency`

It should be 12 in your case, but you might want to reduce it to 10 or 8 if you want to keep some CPU's free for your apache. [This guy here](http://www.theadminzone.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8150) explains some other things you might want to do to tweak MySQL. You still have a lot of memory available, so you should get away with caching more queries.

Comment: After increasing thread_concurrency to 12 i can see that my sites are faster than previous. Thanks for your help.Is there any other tips that can keep more faster of my sites.

Comment: Like I said you can increase query caching. If you find this answer useful, you can vote it up and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You have lots of apache processes because you have lots of connected users (browsers).  If you limit the connection count, then some users will get connection refused.  You'll also notice on that screenshot that mysql is using 2.6 Cores worth of CPU on your server.

You have busy websites, you need to work on reducing the load by reducing the processing requirements of the sites.  Make queries more efficient, reduce script processing times, etc.  Without knowing what your sites do, it's not possible to provide more specific advice.

Basically - your server is busy because it's busy.  You don't want to limit connections (potentially), you want to make those connections more efficient.

Comment: For samples please check the 2 sites below taking too much time to load, please tell specifically what can i command via ssh and where so that my sites can load quickly.

http://www.bookmarktou.com/
http://www.bendasite.com/

Comment: That doesn't provide any sourcecode...plus we told you what the problem is, you should be able to figure it out yourself. If you can't then you need to hire a consultant.